# Passing jsx element in an array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to create check all functionality in ant form. So I have passed Jsx elements in array to use it in checkbox group. But in browser it is giving me object object. Also I have tried to do this without checkbox group, but unable to do so. How can I get checkbox element from object and select all.

Below is my jsx code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Form, Radio, Divider, Input, Checkbox, Select, Button, Row, Col
} from "antd";
const CheckboxGroup = Checkbox.Group;

const ChkComponent = () => {
  const [extra, setExtra] = useState('');
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState([]);
  const [indeterminate, setIndeterminate] = useState(false);
  const [checkAll, setCheckAll] = useState(false);
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const plainOptions = [
    `${<Form.Item className="form-content">
      <Checkbox>chk A</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>
      }`,
    `${<Form.Item 
      name="chkb"
      label={<Checkbox>chk B</Checkbox>} 
      className="form-content" 
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please select an option',
        },
      ]}
      >
      <Select defaultValue="" className="form-input">
        <Select.Option value=""></Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value="a">A</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value="b">B</Select.Option>
      </Select>
      </Form.Item>}`, 
    `${<Form.Item className="form-content">
        <Checkbox>Intermediate Data</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>}`
];

  const onChange = (list) => {
    console.log(plainOptions.length)
    setCheckedList(list);
    setIndeterminate(!!list.length && list.length < plainOptions.length);
    setCheckAll(list.length === plainOptions.length);
  };

  const onCheckAllChange = (e) => {
    setCheckedList(e.target.checked ? plainOptions : []);
    setIndeterminate(false);
    setCheckAll(e.target.checked);
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
    form.validateFields(['folderpath','sdtmoption','adammetadataoption','sdtmmetadataoption']);
    setExtra('Folder Path: ~/datasdtmplus/*.sas7bdat')
    console.log(extra)
  };

  return (
    <>
      
        <div className="container">
          <Form
            wrapperCol={{ span: 12 }}
            layout="horizontal"
            size={12}
            onFinish={onFinish}
          >
            
            <Row>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item className='form-content'>
                  <Checkbox indeterminate={indeterminate} onChange={onCheckAllChange} checked={checkAll}>
                    Check all
                  </Checkbox>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Divider className="form-devider"/>
            <Row>
              
              <Col span={12}>
                <CheckboxGroup options={plainOptions} value={checkedList} onChange={onChange} />
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Divider className="form-devider" />
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ChkComponent;
```

Comment: Are you working with Ant Design?

Comment: yes, ant design form. A check all checkbox and other checkboxes are in different form item.

Comment: You are using `plainOptions` wrong, let me have a look

Comment: Is it mandatory to use `plainOptions` in your app?  If not mandatory, you'd better use `List`

Comment: No, Its not mandatory. My final objective is to implement check all functionality with same form structure.

Comment: Yes, you can use `List` in your current form, of course.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-rumple-ivb29i?file=/src/App.js Please have a look at this

Comment: If you want to customize the options of Checkbox, I think you should put the custom React component via `label`, like in this example https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/checkbox/demo/group.tsx.

This expression ``${X}`` will return a string and in your code, it tries to parse the component into a string. That's why `[object Object]` is displayed